# help with simple pagination code

Tags: php, jquery, pagination

The following piece of code (found on stackoverflow website) selects the pre-uploaded images. The code and demo is here:
http://jsfiddle.net/BshUj/2/

This works fine, however there is something I'd like to change. In case of large number of images, the images list gets very long, therefore I'd like to display only a fixed number of images at once, lets say 10 images, and if there are more than 10 images, I can add some simple pagination at the bottom. Can someone please help me with adding pagination in the image select list as given in above example? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There are plugins all over for this.  Here's one I found with a quick google.

http://tutorialzine.com/2010/05/sweet-pages-a-jquery-pagination-solution/